# Combining multiple .TXT files into one if a string matches in filename

Tags: vbscript

Can someone help me with a requirement where I have list of files in a directory, I want to Merge the files if a pattern of string matches in filenames?

```
AAAL_555A_ORANGE1_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555A_ORANGE2_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555A_ORANGE3_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555A_ORANGE4_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555A_MANGO_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555A_MANGO2_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555B_APPLE_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555B_ORANGE_F190404.TXT
AAAL_555B_Orange_F190404.TXT
```

If second part of `filename='555A'` and third part consists of `ORANGE` then all Oranges content files will merger into one file with filename as `AAAl_555A_ORANGE.txt`.

If second part of `filename='555B'` and third part consists of `ORANGE` then all Oranges content files will merger into one file with filename as `AAAl_555B_ORANGE.txt`.

If second part of `filename='555A'` and third part consists of `MANGO` then all Oranges content files will merger into one file with filename as `AAAl_555A_MANGO.txt`, etc.

```
Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "C:\test"
Set objfolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colfiles = objfolder.Files
'intFile = FreeFile()
For Each objFile In colfiles
    temparr1 = Split(objFile.Name, "_")
    MsgBox temparr1(2)
    If (InStr(1, temparr1(1), "555A") > 0 Or InStr(1, temparr1(1), "555A")) > 0 And (InStr(1, temparr1(2), "ORANGE ") > 0 Or InStr(1, temparr1(2), "ORANGE ")) Then
        'Here the logic am trying to figure out
        'Merge all orange files into "AAAL_ORANGE _555A.txt"
    ElseIf InStr(1, temparr1(1), "555A") > 0 Or InStr(1, temparr1(1), "555A") > 0 Or InStr(1, temparr1(2), "MANGO") > 0 Or InStr(1, temparr1(2), "MANGO") Then
        'Here the logic am trying to figure out
        'Merge all orange files into  "AAAL_MANGO_555A.txt"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Does the order in which the content of the files is added matter?

Comment: It doesn't matters.But while merging first and last three lines should ignore in all files @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FileSystemObject.OpenTextFile()` method has parameters that allow you to specify that you want to a) create the file in case it doesn't exist already, and b) append new content to the end of the file.

In your particular scenario that would probably look somewhat like this:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "\d+$"

For Each objFile In colfiles
    a = Split(objFile.Name, "_")

    'Construct the basename of the output file from the elements of the split
    'input filename. Use a regular expression replacement to remove trailing
    'digits from the third element.
    basename = a(0) & "_" & a(1) & "_" & re.Replace(a(2), "")
    filename = basename & ".txt"

    If Left(objFile.Name, Len(basename)) = basename Then
        Set outFile = ObjFSO.OpenTextFile(filename, 8, True)
        Set inFile  = ObjFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path)
        Do Until inFile.AtEndOfStream
            outFile.WriteLine inFile.ReadLine
        Loop
        inFile.Close
        outFile.Close
    End If
Next
```

For omitting lines from beginning or end of the input files see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38933840/1630171) to a similar question.

Comment: I have tried the code provided but the files are not getting mergerd@Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @anilbusupalli The code worked just fine when I tested it. Beware that it's not a turnkey solution. You need to integrate it with the rest of your code. Also beware that the output files are created in the current working directory. Define `filename` with the full path to get the output in a particular folder.